# How do you say "I will have (something) in Mandarin?

Tags: mandarin

Is it correct if i say: Wo jiang you (the o in you has the v tone)

Does that mean "I have" in future tense?

Comment: give a full example sentence you're looking to express

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use 我將有.

For example,
我將有一週的假期。
I will have a week of vacation.
I will have a one-week holiday.

Comment: Does "我会有" also work, just perhaps less formal?

Comment: Yes. But it's better to give a time indicator like, say 下个月.  我下个月会有一周的假期。